# Solution to mimic enum inheritance in cpp

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

I know that enum inheritance is not possible in c++, but I am looking for specific data structure that simply fit into my case. Suppose I have these two enums:

```
    enum Fruit { apple, orange};
    enum Drink { water, milk};
```

I want a parent for these two that I can use as parameter in this abstract method

```
   void LetsEat(Eatable eatable){}
```

They are going to be used as simple switches, and basically I want to keep my code clean and type safe. I wonder if I will be forced to use inherited classes that needs to be initialized. It is too much for this simple problem.

Comment: Side note, but you might want to consider using `enum class`. Ignoring the horrible misnomer of a name (it's not a class, don't think of it that way), it improves on regular enums in several ways, most namely by making it harder to accidentally cast between your enum type and raw integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speaking very generally, `enum`s are just dressed up `int`s.

```
enum Fruit { apple, orange};
```

If you look at the compiled code, you will discover that an `apple` will be represented by the value 0, and an `orange` will be represented by the value 1.

```
enum Drink { water, milk};
```

Same thing here will happen here. `water` will be represented by value 0, and `milk` will be represented by value 1. You can begin to see the obvious problem here.

One, a slightly primitive, solution is equivalent to letting a bull loose in the china shop:

```
enum Drink { water=2, milk=3};
```

Now you could cook something up where you're passing in a `int` value and figure out what exactly was passed in, by its value.

But this will likely require plenty of ugly casts, everywhere. The resulting code, if posted to Stackoverflow, will likely to attract downvotes.

The downvotes will be because there are cleaner solutions that are available in modern, post C++17 world. For starters, you can switch to `enum` classes.

```
enum class Fruit { apple, orange};
enum class Drink { water, milk};
```

This gains additional type-safety. It's not as easy, any more, to assign a `Fruit` to a `Drink`. Your C++ compiler will bark, very loudly, in many situations where it would raise a warning. Your C++ compiler will help you find even more bugs, in your code. It is true that this will require a little bit more typing. You will always have to specify enumerated values everywhere with full qualification, i.e. `Fruit::apple` and `Drink::water`, when in your existing code a mere `apple` and `water` will suffice. But a few extra typed characters is a small price to pay for more type-safe code, and for being able to simply declare:

```
typedef std::variant<Fruit, Drink> Eatable;
```

and simply do what you always wanted:

```
void LetsEat(Eatable eatable){}
```

and everything will work exactly how you wanted it. `LetsEat` will accept either a `Fruit` or a `Drink` as its parameter. It will have to do a little bit more work, to figure out what's in the `std::variant`, but nobody ever claimed that C++ is easy.

`std::variant` is one of the more complex templates in the C++ library, and it's not possible to explain how to use it, fully, in a short paragraph or two on Stackoverflow. But this is what's possible, and I'll refer you to your C++ textbook for a complete description of how to use this template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it is possible to feed new enams to variant when a new enum is created. I mean suppose variant is defined in a common location, and I don't want to modify that.

Comment: You can always add new types to a variant. But you have to change its definition. And it's a good thing. You may think it's a bother to have to recompile everything that uses the variant. But you will learn, over time, how to write failproof code -- typically using `std::visit` -- that must support all possible variant values. Even if you forget about its existence, your C++ compiler will find it and report a compilation error when a new value gets added to the variant.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like an excellent use case for [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

// Define our enums
enum Fruit { Apple, Orange };
enum Drink { Water, Milk };

// An Eatable is either a Fruit or a Drink
using Eatable = std::variant<Fruit, Drink>;

void letsEat(Eatable eatable) {
  // We can use the index() method to figure out which one we have
  switch (eatable.index()) {
  case 0:
    std::cout << "It's a Fruit!" << std::endl;
    break;
  case 1:
    std::cout << "It's a Drink!" << std::endl;
    break;
  }
}

int main() {
  letsEat(Apple);
  letsEat(Water);
}
```

Note that `std::variant<Fruit, Drink>` is not, strictly speaking, a supertype of `Fruit` or `Drink`. Instead, it's a new type altogether but we get implicit conversions from `Fruit` and `Drink` *to* `std::variant<Fruit, Drink>` via its constructors.

If you're not using C++17, you can use `boost::variant` from the Boost C++ libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::variant<T, ...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) if you use C++17 or above:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

enum Fruit { apple, orange };
enum Drink { water, milk };

using Eatable = std::variant<Fruit, Drink>;

void LetsEat(Eatable const eatable) {
    std::visit([] (auto&& v) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(v)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Fruit>) {
            // Now use it like you would use a normal 'Fruit' variable ...
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Drink>) {
            // Now use it like you would use a normal 'Drink' variable ...
        }
    }, eatable);
}

int main() {
    LetsEat(apple);
}
```

Alternatively, you could just create a class that is implicitly convertible to either `enum` type:

```cpp
class Eatable {
    union {
        Fruit f;
        Drink d;
    } u_;
    bool has_fruit_;
public:
    Eatable(Fruit f) : has_fruit_(true) {
        u_.f = f;
    };
    Eatable(Drink d) : has_fruit_(false) {
        u_.d = d;
    };
    operator Fruit() const {
        return u_.f;
    }
    operator Drink() const {
        return u_.d;
    }
    bool has_fruit() const {
        return has_fruit_;
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```cpp
void LetsEat(Eatable const eatable) {
    if (eatable.has_fruit()) {
        Fruit const f = eatable;
        switch (f) {
            case apple:
                std::cout << "Fruit: apple" << std::endl;
                break;
            case orange:
                std::cout << "Fruit: orange" << std::endl;
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    } else {
        Drink const d = eatable;
        switch (d) {
            case water:
                std::cout << "Drink: water" << std::endl;
                break;
            case milk:
                std::cout << "Drink: milk" << std::endl;
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```